# How to fix screen tearing of the Nvidia 675m gtx in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I tried to use the common methods: In nvidia X server settings and compiz-manager, but the Vblank option and the screen refresh rate is missing.

If i switch back to my intel 4000hd card, everything works fine.

I am using the 331.113 property driver for ubuntu.